# кириллица в термальном принтере

Tags: java, кодировка, кириллица

взял код отсюда http://www.mets-blog.com/java-pos-thermal-printer-example/
там смущает вот эта строка 
`bytes = text.getBytes("CP437");`
в других кодировках крякозябры в общем как заставить печатать кириллицу?

Answer (score 6):

Наверное все носители тайного знания как заставить печатать туповатый принтер кириллицу просто тупо вымерли и я остался один. А ведь были золотые времена в святые 90-е это была вообще золотая тема :)

В принтере в евонной памяти содержится некая таблица, в которую загружены шрифты и где напротив байта - стоит его буквенное изображение. Когда принтеру приходит команда печатать байт, он берет байт с ним идет в таблицу извлекает оттуда символ и посылает сигнал своим головкам *изобразить символ*. Соответственно, задача прогера состоит в том, чтобы шрифты загруженные в память принтера получали правильные байты (кодировка) или же если нет шрифтов загрузить таковые в принтер. Обычно это задача драйвера - драйвер берет на себя эту непосильную задачу.

Соответственно, задача распадается в нашем случае на 2 части:

1. Загрузка шрифтов - зависит от модели принтера, обычно в мануале подробно описывается сей процесс (или решается тупо установкой драйвера). В тупых моделях принтеров бывает загружен только 1 шрифт с кодировкой CP-437 (US)
2. Перекодировка байтов (если требуется - зависит от кодировки шрифта)

В общем давайте модель принтера - оттуда и будем плясать.

**Update**

В мануале расписаны ESC коды управления принтером. По идее, это все должен делать драйвер, но можно и самому.

Вам надо сначала перед печатью выставить кодовую страницу, что достигается следующей ESC последовательностью:

```
ESC t n
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По простому надо в порт принтера записать три байта:

```
0x1B 0x74 0x11  //байты приведены в HEX (ESC t 17)
```

После чего надо посылать ваш текст, но уже в кодировке KOI-8

Рекомендуется перед этим проинициализировать принтер посылкой команды

```
ESC @
```

Comment: Вон оно чё! Оказывается в принтере ещё и таблица содержится! Сколько раз разбирал принтеры, не разу таблицу не находил.

Comment: xprinter XP-T300H
http://xprinter.com.ua/terms--conditions.html
там есть мануал и на стр. 29 табличке
`n  Page 
0  PC437 [U.S.A.Standard Europe] 
1  Katakana 
2  PC850:Multilingual 
3  PC860:Portuguese 
4  PC863 [Canadian French] 
5  PC865:Nodic 
6  West Europe 
7  Greek 
8  Hebrew 
9  PC755:East Europe 
10  Iran 
16  WPC1252 
17  PC866:Cyrillic#2 
18  PC852:Latin2 
19  PC858 
20  IranII 
21  Latvian `
т.е. на 17ом `PC866:Cyrillic#2`

Comment: и появится другой вопрос что за кодировка **PC866** разве не **CP866** ?

Comment: @Barmaley спасибо за советы!
сделал чуть по другому:
`ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        out.write( 27 ); // ESC
        out.write( 116 ); // t
        out.write( 17 ); // 866 codepage
        out.write( "Привет".getBytes("CP866" ) );`
вроде как работает, теперь остается разобраться работа с jasperreports )

Comment: Ну дык, это то же самое что я написал, просто в десятичном коде :) Удачи

Answer (score 2):

Кодировка [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) не содержит кирилицы. Если у вас символы кирилицы закодированны например в русскую кодировку [CP1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) или [КОИ-8](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%9E%D0%98-8), то на выходе у вас получится набор байт, который нельзя показать ввиду сказанного выше. Поэтому вам скорее всего надо декодировать в другую кодировку, содержащую кирилицу. Но возможен вариант трансфера где декодированные байты можно обратно закодировать с помощью того же CP437 и в результате у вас получится строка в прежней кодировке.

Comment: у меня текст который перекодируется в CP437 закодирован на UTF-8, пробовал указать и CP1251 и КОИ-8 получаю не понятно что...

Comment: я как раз об этом и писал...

Comment: интересно, создал обычный текстовой документ на нотпад++ кодировка ютф8
русские символы напечатались

Comment: когда данные заканчиваются в потоке, то поток закрывается