# Как убрать окно подтверждения печати на термопринтере?

Tags: java, принтер

В java разбираюсь, но с принтерами вожусь впервые.

У меня термопринтер ocmo OCPP-808. Подключен к компьютеру через ЮСБ.
Хотел напечатать что-то из JAVA.

Нашел на [исходник гитхабе](https://github.com/picharras/print-with-Java/).
Работает отлично, но не устраивает то, что при запуске открывается окошко и я должен нажать на кнопку принт, чтобы печатать чек.

Можно ли как то убрать это окошко, чтобы чек печатался при запуске приложения?

```
class Main {

public static String contentTicket = "Label Илхом";
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
    byte[] bytes = contentTicket.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    System.out.print(bytes);
    PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(bytes, flavor, null);
    PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

    Book book = new Book();
    PageFormat landscape = pjob.defaultPage();
    DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();

    landscape.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
    book.append(new Printable1(), landscape);
    PageFormat portrait = pjob.defaultPage();
    portrait.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);
    book.append(new Printable2(), portrait, 0);
    pjob.setPageable(book);
    try {
        job.print(doc,pras);
        pjob.print();
    } catch (PrinterException e) {
    } catch (PrintException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
class Printable1 implements Printable {
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int pageIndex) {
    drawGraphics(g, pf);
    return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
}
public void drawGraphics(Graphics g, PageFormat pf){
}
}
class Printable2 implements Printable {
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int pageIndex) {
    drawGraphics(g, pf);
    return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
}
public void drawGraphics(Graphics g, PageFormat pf){
}
}
```

Comment: Посмотрел исходник, о каком окошке то речь?

Comment: Окошко печати принтера. Выходить же при печати с ворда например. Вроде такой. В исходнике его не зовут. ОС его открывает. При нажатии идет печать.

Comment: может этот пример поможет? http://www.mets-blog.com/java-pos-thermal-printer-example/

Comment: Я еще вчера нашел этот пример. По нему выдает это:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.company.PrinterService.printString(PrinterService.java:69)
 at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:23)  *****На строке DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();

Comment: @ilx13 правильно ли указали принтер?

Comment: Да. еще русские буквы не печатает, только английские. Русские отображаются на термобумаге как иероглифы. Как решить проблему? СПасибо

Answer (score 1):

недавно я сам сталкивался с такой проблемой вот [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/856738/%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5/856755#856755)
и решил таким путем

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
out.write(27); // ESC
out.write(116); // t
out.write(17); // 866 codepage
out.write(text.getBytes("CP866"));
byte[] bytes;
bytes = out.toByteArray();
```

а кстати вы должны ещё посмотреть мануал по вашему принтеру т.к. там  ESC коды могут быть другие...

Comment: Muzaffar Rasulov, не понял что делает ваш код. Если я приведу свой код печати Вы можете подгонять его под кирилицу, если Вам извество его фишки?

Comment: Ну, код в студию... ☺ попробуем разбираться

Comment: Muzaffar Rasulov, добавил код на вопрос. Благодарен за внимание.

Comment: попробуйте вот так:

вместо `byte[] bytes = contentTicket.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

поставить то что я предлагал, т.е.
    `ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    out.write(27); // ESC
    out.write(116); // t
    out.write(17); // 866 codepage
    out.write(contentTicket.getBytes("CP866"));
    byte[] bytes;
    bytes = out.toByteArray();`

Comment: не знаю как правильно форматировать код в комментах

Comment: премного благодарен все печатается очень красиво в кирилице. Но в конце добавляется "ОН". Когда печатаю "Магаз Илхом" - печатается как "Магаз Илхом". Не знаете в чем можеть быть проблема?

Comment: не понял чем отличается первое **"Магаз Илхом"** от второго **печатается как "Магаз Илхом"**?

Comment: Muzaffar Rasulov, прощу прощения, печатает "Магаз ИлхомОН" добавляет из себя "ОН" на все что печатаю. До моих разных эксперементов такого не было. Печаталось норм на анг буквы. Сейчас пробовал на анг печатать, все равно добавляет "ОН". Я днем торгую на рынке у меня не большой магазин, устал немного поэтому ошибся на предыдущем комментарии.

Comment: Muzaffar Rasulov, можете помочь?

Comment: @ilx13 что говорит дебаггер?